# GoBack get called 3times uwp

Tags: c#, windows-phone, uwp

If i press the backbutton on my phone the GoBack method get called 3 times and i go to the start page insted of the previous page (but it works 1 time of 20). But on the PC it workes every time with only one call and Always get to the previous page.

This is the startMethod in the class:

```
 public DetailPageFavorites()
        {
       this.InitializeComponent();
        // If on a phone device that has hardware buttons then we hide the app's back button.
        if (ApiInformation.IsTypePresent("Windows.Phone.UI.Input.HardwareButtons"))
        {
            this.BackButton.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
            this.button_like.Margin = new Thickness(0, 0, 0, 0);
        }
        SystemNavigationManager.GetForCurrentView().BackRequested += SystemNavigationManager_BackRequested;
}
```

Method used if hardwareButton is pressent:

```
   private void SystemNavigationManager_BackRequested(object sender, BackRequestedEventArgs e)
    {
        Frame frame = Window.Current.Content as Frame;
        e.Handled = true;
        if (frame.CanGoBack)
        {
            frame.GoBack();
        }

    }
```

Methods used on the PC:

```
 private void BackButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            GoBack();
        }
        private void GoBack()
        {
            Frame frame = Window.Current.Content as Frame;
            if (frame == null)
            {
                return;
            }
            if (frame.CanGoBack)
            {
                frame.GoBack();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you remove `SystemNavigationManager.GetForCurrentView().BackRequested` event handler before navigate to other page.

Either at`Page.Unloaded` event or `OnNavigatedFrom` method.

```
protected override void OnNavigatedFrom(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
            base.OnNavigatedFrom(e);
            SystemNavigationManager.GetForCurrentView().BackRequested -= SystemNavigationManager_BackRequested;
}
```